# return atleast top-n rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using panda and python and I have the DF similar to below:

```
id    student   courses
0     A         1
1     F         2
2     B         5
3     C         2
4     D         4
5     H         5
```

and I want to select at least top-3 students with the most courses. and get something like this:

```
id  student courses
2   B       5
5   H       5
4   D       4
1   F       2
3   C       2
```

the returned DF has 5 rows because I need to show all the students who attended courses equally to the last student of the top-3.

my code:

```
sorted_list = students_DF.sort_values(by=["courses"], ascending=False)
n=3 #top-3
return_df = sorted_list[:n]
for i, row in sorted_list.iterrows():
       if return_df.iloc[n-1]['mag'] == sorted_list.iloc[n]['mag']:
         return_df.append(sorted_list.iloc[n], ignore_index=True)
```

for some reason, I can't get it to append rows. any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `np.unique` to extract the max courses, then `isin`:

```
max_courses = np.unique(df.courses)[-3:]

df[df.courses.isin(max_courses)]
```

Output:

```
   id student  courses
1   1       F        2
2   2       B        5
3   3       C        2
4   4       D        4
5   5       H        5
```

Comment: FYI Reader: This works because `np.unique` sorts the unique values.  `pd.unique` or `df.courses.unique()` does not sort and could lead to incorrect results.

Comment: I had to sort the rows after performing the above. thanks both of you!

Comment: it works but there is an issue, I'm not looking for the n max_courses. my aim is to get top n students with the highest courses and show any other similarity if exist. the code above will return n courses and map students to them.